# How to add subtotals in a multi_index dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Is it possible to enable totals for a `MultiIndex` `pandas.DataFrame`, for chosen index levels?

Let say the `DataFrame` has 3 levels, I want to be able to display a (sub)total line either for the 1st level, or the second, or the 1st and 3rd level, etc...

I tried without success the usage of the `margin` setting with the `pivot_table` function, but it only display the whole total for both line and columns, which has little interest in case of a `MultiIndex`.

Comment: You will need to calculate subtotals then concatenate to original dataframe.   Add some data to this questions and someone in SO will show you how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62605602/6361531  Try this sample.

Comment: thanks, the background idea made the trick (just had to call it at several layers).